# Any way to convert pandas DataFrame itertuples object to dictionary without using a private function?

Tags: python, pandas

This is what I want to do drive a computational experiment

```py
import pandas
def foo(a = 1, b = 2):
    print("In foo with %s" % str(locals()))
    return a + b


def expand_grid(dictionary):
    from itertools import product
    return pandas.DataFrame([row for row in product(*dictionary.values())], columns=dictionary.keys())


experiment = {"a":[1,2], "b":[10,12]}
grid = expand_grid(experiment)

for g in grid.itertuples(index=False):
    foo(**g._asdict())
```

That works, but the issue is it has a private _asdict() call.  There is a standard in Python not to use "_" calls in external code, so here is my question:

Can you do the above without the _asdict() and if so how?

Also note while  foo(a =g.a, b=g.b) is a solution, the actual code is a heavily parameterized call, and for my own knowledge, I was just trying to figure out how to treat it as kwargs without the _ call if it was possible.

Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the final thing you want is.

Comment: I want exactly the output of the above code.  It is the code itself that I want to change.  Output is fine.

Comment: just do `grid.to_dict(orient='records')` and do not loop or `[foo(**x) for x in grid.to_dict(orient='records')]` to send the dict to `foo`

Comment: @Yo_Chris
Perfect thanks.

Background note on why I cared.  I have seen some package devs be pretty serious about not using "_", so I had this anti-pattern above i was trying to see my way out of.  Thanks for the tip it works.